# Why are there no excitations by collision for the visible transitions in the Franck-Hertz experiment?

Tags: energy, collision, photon-emission

The minima of the I(V) graph for a Neon Franck-Hertz tube are approximately 20V apart from each other, this is usually explained by the fact that excitation by inelastic collision happens at about 20 eV.

Neon has the advantage of easily visible excitation regions, they glow orange. This tells us that there are also transitions in the range of few eV.

Why are those transitions not suitable for excitation by the electrons?